# Why does my javascript clock crash after a minute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have double checked and tested on jshint for syntax errors and such. I have also compared my code to others who created the same clock, but did not see any differences that would cause my clock to crash. I do not understand what is causing this problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function displayTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var miridiem = "AM";

    var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');

    if(seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds
    }

    if(minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes
    }

    if (hours > 12) {
      hours = hours - 12
      miridiem = "PM"
    }

    if (hours === 0) {
      hours = 12
    }

    clockDiv.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + miridiem;

    setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
  }

  displayTime();
});
```

```html
<body>
 
  <div id="clock"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

*Warning: snippet will eat your memory. Don't forget to stop it.*

https://jsfiddle.net/9cp9m43h/

Comment: You should use `setTimeout` and not `setInterval`

Comment: You're calling `setInterval()` every second, meaning you are exponentially creating more timers every single second. I think you meant to use `setTimeout()` instead, or you can keep `setInterval()`, but place it *outside* the `displayTime()` function.

Comment: I just changed it and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I just looked up the details on `setInterval()`. So basically, I was calling the `displayTime()` function every 1000ms?

Comment: @Archatype Yes, but multiple times - because each time you created a new interval that called that function again.

Comment: @Archatype: You called `displayTime()` once after 1 second, then twice after 2 seconds, and so forth. On the 60th second, you were calling it 60 times.

Comment: @Archatype: Actually, scratch that--you called it once after 1 second, twice after 2 seconds, four times after three seconds, eight after four seconds, and so on. So after sixty seconds, you were calling it a billion billion times.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, no. 1s - 1, 2s - 2, 3s - 4, Ns - 2^(N-1). So at 60s it will eat too much memory, not just 60 calls.

Comment: @vp_arth: Right, I already corrected myself. You'd basically have a quintillion (short-scale) timers set after 60 seconds, which would be insane both from a CPU and a memory standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just misunderstanding the usage of `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

As some commenters mentioned, you could just change your current implementation to use `setTimeout` and it would function pretty well.

However, in my opinion, the best solution would be to change the way your code works, so that `setInterval` works correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function displayTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var miridiem = "AM";

    var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');

    if(seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds
    }

    if(minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes
    }

    if (hours > 12) {
      hours = hours - 12
      miridiem = "PM"
    }

    if (hours === 0) {
      hours = 12
    }

    clockDiv.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + miridiem;

  }

  displayTime();
  setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
});
```

I feel this is better because:

1. this is what `setInterval` was designed for: performing the same action over and over at a specific interval.
2. calling `setTimeout` manually to reset the timer leaves you open to some clock skew; if it takes a millisecond for your `displayTime` to run before it sets the timeout, then after 1000 seconds you're probably going to be about 1 second off.
3. a function called `displayTime()` sounds like all it's doing is displaying the time--there's nothing to hint that it's also creating a long-term side-effect. The separation of concerns feels better if the timer is set outside of that method.
4. The effects of `displayTime()` are easier to test independently when it's not creating asynchronous side-effects.

Comment: Hmm, i'm having a hard time figuring out how it crashed with the `setInterval()` within the `displayTime()` function, but working completely fine outside the function.

Comment: @Archatype: Imagine you have a phone with a timer app and you want to check on something every minute. Suppose the timer app has two types of timers you can set: One will automatically reset itself each time it rings, and the other will just stop when it rings. Your original approach was like using an auto-reset timer, but then manually setting another auto-reset timer every time a timer went off. After the second minute, you'd get both timers going off, one right after the other, but if you set new timers both times then after three minutes you'd have four timers going off, and so on.

Comment: @Archatype: Using the same analogy, switching to `setTimeout` is like using a timer that just stops when it rings, and you manually set it to remind you again a minute later. On the other hand, if you use `setInterval` and just put it outside of the callback, that's like using an auto-reset timer and only setting it once.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `setInterval()` is in the wrong place. You placed it inside the function, which is registering 60 interval monitors per minute so the memory is crashing. If you wanted to trigger the next timeout after the function has been called, you can do that using `setTimeout()`, within the `displayTime()` function. But if you do `setInterval()`, you want that to be called at the same level that your initial `displayTime()` function is called.

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cp9m43h/3/

Answer (score 0):

every time `displayTime()` is called it starts a new Interval that calls `displayTime()` every second.

Therefore every second the function is called twice as often as the time before. After 60 Seconds this is `Math.pow(2, 60) //=> 1152921504606847000` times.

> Hmm, i'm having a hard time figuring out how it crashed with the setInterval() within the displayTime() function, but working completely fine outside the function.

Because in this case `displayTime()` is not calling itself not even a roundtrip over setInterval. So it stays a single Interval, and therefore a single function-call every second.